Angular: how to dynamically inject a HTML code with angular syntax in to a div tag at runtime
its been a while I wrote Angular code, so looking for some help.
I want to be able to take an input from user at runtime that may look like below:
<div *ngIf="isValid;else other_content">content here ...</div><ng-template #other_content>other content here...</ng-template>

and assign it to a div that looks like <div id=dynamicContainer></div> in my view component.
I tried to use the following code, which works as long as there is no angular in it.
  private injectTemplate(template: string) {
    const dynamicContainer = this.document.getElementById('dynamicContainer');
    if (dynamicContainer) {
      this.renderer.setProperty(dynamicContainer, 'innerHTML', template);
    }
  }

However, once the angular code is embedded like text binding or condition, it fails.
in the past, there used to be compiler service to do such things; however, it's deprecated now.
can someone please help me with a code that is able to compile the above template code and inject it inside the <div id=dynamicContainer></div>

This is doable by leverage the JIT compiler but this is not recommended for several reasons :

This pulls the compiler package into the runtime. That additional JS loaded by the client.
Long term speaking, the Angular doesn't recommend starting using JIT , as AOT compilation is clearly the present & future of Angular.


That being said, here is a working example :
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: '<div #container></div>',
  standalone: true,
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
  container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
    private environement: EnvironmentInjector
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // runInContext is important to allow DI with inject()
    this.environement.runInContext(() => {
      const clazz = class {
        private foo = inject(Foo); // From the local provider
        private bar = inject(Bar); // From the global provider
        public test;

        constructor() {
          this.test = 'some value';
          console.log(this.foo.rand, this.bar.rand);
        }
      };

      // Here is the trick to change the class name
      Object.defineProperty(clazz, 'name', { value: 'TheName' });

      // Define the component using Component decorator.
      const component = Component({
        selector: 'test',
        template:
          '<div>This is the dynamic template.<br> Test value: {{test}}</div>',
        styles: [':host {color: red}'],
        providers: [{ provide: Foo, useClass: Foo }],
      })(clazz);
      console.log(component);

      const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(component, {
        injector: this.injector,
      });

      timer(0, 1000).subscribe((val) => {
        componentRef.instance.test = val % 2 ? 'tic' : 'tac';
      });
    });
  }
}

Stackblitz

Thanks @MatthieuRiegler, I tried to use your Stackblitz and make some changes to introduce the angular *ngIf as seen in the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-temecr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts however its is unable to manage that part.     any idea what I am missing

Good question, I'm not sure what's happening. If you are on v17+ you can use the control flow syntax.

Interesting, it works when using the control flow syntax, however, my original application is in Angular 16, so I guess this is not possible there. if you ever find out how to fix this with *ngIf please let me know.

For this in Angular we use string interpolation {{ myVariable }}.
In your component.ts myVariable = 'Some text'
